# Authentication system logs users in although they are not activated

Tags: php, oop, eloquent, slim

i'm learning PHP and i started directly with OOP. So i tried to build a complete loginsystem including user activation via email -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJJXCni8mNc .

But i've a problem right now. Users are able to login, although they are not activated. Of course i checked the database. `active` is set to `0` after registration and if i understood the code correct, users only should be loged in, when `active` is `true`. I'm checking that inside my `login.php`

```
if ($v->passes()){
    $user = $app->user
        ->where('username', $identifier)
        ->orWhere('email', $identifier)
        ->where('active', true)
        ->first
```

I added my `register.php` `user.php` and `login.php` and i hope someone can tell me where my mistake is.

**register.php**

```
<?php

use ZESI\User\UserPermission;

$app -> get('/register', $guest(), function() use ($app){
$app->render('auth/register.php');

})->name('register');

$app -> post('/register', $guest(), function() use ($app) {

$request = $app->request;

$email = $request->post('email');
$username = $request->post('username');
$password = $request->post('password');
$password2 = $request->post('password2');

$v = $app->validation;

$v->validate([
        'email' => [$email, 'required|email|uniqueEmail'],
        'username' => [$username, 'required|alnumDash|max(20)|uniqueUsername'],
        'password' => [$password, 'required|min(6)'],
        'password2' => [$password2, 'required|matches(password)'],
    ]); 

if ($v->passes()){

        $identifier = $app->randomlib->generateString(128);

        $user = $app->user->create([
        'email' => $email,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $app->hash->password($password),
        'active' => false,
        'active_hash' => $app->hash->hash($identifier),
    ]);

    $user->permissions()->create(UserPermission::$defaults);


    $app->mail->send('email/auth/registered.php', ['user' => $user, 'identifier' => $identifier], function ($message) use ($user){
        $message->to($user->email);
        $message->subject('Ihre Registrierung');
    });

    $app->flash('global', 'Registrierung erfolgreich');
    $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));
} 

$app->render('auth/register.php', [
        'errors' => $v->errors(),
        'request' => $request,
    ]);



})->name('register.post');
```

**user.php**

```
<?php

namespace ZESI\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'username',
    'password',
    'active',
    'active_hash',
    'remember_identifier',
    'remember_token',
];


public function getFullName(){

    if (!$this->firstname || !$this->lastname){
        return null;
    }

    return "{$this->firstname} {$this->lastname}";
}

public function getFullNameOrUsername(){
    return $this->getFullName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function activateAccount(){

    $this->update([
            'active' => true,
            'active_hash' => null
        ]);
}

public function getAvatarUrl($options = []){

    $size = isset($options['size']) ? $options['size']: 45;

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5($this->email) . '?s=' . $size . '&d=identicon';
}

public function updateRememberCredentials($identifier, $token){
    $this->update([
            'remember_identifier' => $identifier,
            'remember_token' => $token,
        ]);
}

public function removeRememberCredentials(){
    $this->updateRememberCredentials(null, null);
}

public function hasPermission($permission){
    return (bool) $this->permissions->{$permission};
}

public function isAdmin(){
    return $this->hasPermission('is_admin');
}

public function permissions(){
    return $this->hasOne('ZESI\User\UserPermission', 'user_id');
}


}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;

$app->get('/login', $guest(), function() use ($app) {

$app->render('auth/login.php');

})->name('login');

$app->post('/login', $guest(), function() use ($app){

$request = $app->request;

$identifier = $request->post('identifier');
$password = $request->post('password');
$remember = $request->post('remember');

$v = $app->validation;

$v->validate([
        'identifier' => [$identifier, 'required'],
        'password' => [$password, 'required']
    ]);

if ($v->passes()){
    $user = $app->user
        ->where('username', $identifier)
        ->orWhere('email', $identifier)
        ->where('active', true)
        ->first();


    if ($user && $app->hash->passwordCheck($password, $user->password)){
        $_SESSION[$app->config->get('auth.session')] = $user->id;

        if ($remember === 'on'){
            $rememberIdentifier = $app->randomlib->generateString(128);
            $rememberToken = $app->randomlib->generateString(128);

            $user->updateRememberCredentials(
                $rememberIdentifier,
                $app->hash->hash($rememberToken)
            );

            $app->setCookie(
                $app->config->get('auth.remember'),
                "{$rememberIdentifier}___{$rememberToken}",
                Carbon::parse('+1 week')->timestamp
            );
        }

        $app->flash('global', 'Login erfolgreich');
        $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));

    } else {
        $app->flash('global', 'Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen!');
        $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('login'));
    }

}

$app->render('auth/login.php', [
        'errors' => $v->errors(),
        'requests' => $request
    ]);

})->name('login.post');
```

**EDIT**
not working:

```
->where('active', true)
->where('username', $identifier)
->orWhere('email', $identifier)
->first();
```

working:

```
if ($v->passes()){
        $user = $app->user
            ->where('username', $identifier)
            ->where('active', true)
            ->orWhere('email', $identifier)
            ->where('active', true)
            ->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$identifier = 'jmattheis';
$app->user
    ->where('username', $identifier)
    ->orWhere('email', $identifier)
    ->where('active', true)
```

This would go to SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE `username` = 'jmattheis' OR `email` = 'jmattheis' AND `active` = true
```

This would be `when (username = jmattheis) or (email = jmattheis and active = true)`

You should use `(` or with eloquent use this:

```
$app->user
    ->where(function($query) use ($identifier) {
         $query->where('username', $identifier)
             ->orWhere('email', $identifier);
    })->where('active', true)->first();
```

Comment: Oh great, seems that we get nearer to the solution. Move `->where('active', true)` to the top doesn't change anything. But logging in with the EMailAdress is not possible... so you're right. But why doesn't it help when i change the order and move `active` to the top?

Comment: @Sithys You have the orWhere at the last statement (before the ->first())?

Comment: look at my edit at the bottom of my question. It is not working with changing the order and putting the `active` statement to the top. But it works if i doublecheck the active state for username and email adress - would that be a correct solution or is that not a clean method?

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working. Great to know, how this statement get interpreted. Have to learn a lot, but now its working and total clear for me why it was not!